# getting access to property of HttpModule from page

Tags: asp.net, httpmodule

Is there a way to get access to a property of HttpModule from asp.net page?

```
namespace MyHttpModule
{
    public class Module : IHttpModule
    {
        public string M_Property { get; set; }

        public void Init(HttpApplication context)
        {
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get active modules from ApplicationInstance, for example I have module that saves current RawUrl in BeginRequest :

```
  public class PlainModule : IHttpModule
  {
    private HttpApplication app = null;    
    public string CurrentRequestUrl;

    public void Init(HttpApplication Context)
    {
      this.app = Context;
      Context.BeginRequest += new System.EventHandler(Begin);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
    }

    private void Begin(Object Sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      this.CurrentRequestUrl = this.app.Request.RawUrl;
    }
  }
```

Of course you have to register your module in web.config :

```
  <system.web>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="PlainModule" type="WebApplication1.PlainModule, WebApplication1"/>
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
```

and then you can get module instance using name registered in web config,  like this :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  PlainModule pm = (PlainModule)HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.Modules["PlainModule"];
  Response.Write("Current request URL : "  + pm.CurrentRequestUrl);
}
```